# How to delete a dynamic DNS record using Python or Bash?

Tags: python, dns

The Following code in python updates

```
import dns.query
import dns.tsigkeyring
import dns.update
import sys
 keyring = dns.tsigkeyring.from_text({'host-example.' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='})

update = dns.update.Update('dyn.test.example', keyring=keyring)
update.replace('host', 300, 'a', sys.argv[1])

 response = dns.query.tcp(update, '10.0.0.1')
```

but I could not find out how to remove a dns entry.

Comment: Use the `delete()` method. It's in the documentation, right before the `replace()` method. http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.10.0/html/

Comment: Thanks, I must be blind! It didnt even occur to me to check out the rest of the methods of the Update class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`delete()`](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.14.0/dns.update.Update-class.html#delete) method of `dns.update.Update` can be used to delete a record.

```
import dns.query
import dns.tsigkeyring
import dns.update

keyring = dns.tsigkeyring.from_text({'host-example.' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='})
update = dns.update.Update('dyn.test.example', keyring=keyring)
update.delete('host', 'A')
response = dns.query.tcp(update, '10.0.0.1')
```

Comment: Thanks. But am failing to delete NX and MX records for the origin or "@" zone with this method. Any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Could it be you forget the distance and/or content of a particular MX or NS record at deleting?

Answer (score 1):

The delete method of **dns.update.Update** always takes a name as the first argument. The other arguments can be:

- nothing
- rdataset...
- rdata...
- rdtype, [string...]

Source: http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/

To delete a specific TXT record from the domain _acme-challenge.example.com with the contents "Hello World":

```
import dns.resolver
import dns.tsigkeyring
import dns.update
import dns.query

# Create the rdata object
txt_record = dns.rdata.from_text(dns.rdataclass.IN, dns.rdatatype.TXT, "Hello World")

# Initialize a new DNS update object
update = dns.update.Update('example.com', keyring=keyring)

# Delete the specific record passing in the rdata object
update.delete('_acme-challenge', txt_record)

# Send the request
reponse = dns.query.udp(update, '10.0.0.1', timeout=10)

# Check if the TXT record was successfully removed:
answers = dns.resolver.query('_acme-challenge.example.com', 'TXT')
txt_records = [txt_record.strings[0] for txt_record in answers]
if "Hello World" in txt_records:
    print "TXT record not successfully deleted"
else:
    print "TXT record successfully deleted"
```